# Nest files icons

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I use the extension [FileNesting](https://github.com/madskristensen/FileNesting) in Visual Studio 2013 to group the files of a same angularjs view (html as parent, js and css as children). Unfortunately, the specific file icon for js and css is replaced by a basic icon in the project explorer.

Is there a way to display the specific icon on nested files?